# % After output VSCode Integrated Terminal

Tags: arch-linux, zsh, fonts, visual-studio-code

So I'm running an Arch Linux installation with PowerLevel10k on OhMyZsh.  I have the SynthWave84 theme on Visual Studio Code, and in the Integrated Terminal I get a weird % sign after the program's output.  Everything's set to build based off of a tutorial that I've found, and everything was fine until I switched to Oh My Zsh.  Here's a screenshot of the issue:

[image: as you can see, there's a % after program output.]
So how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way that ZSH indicates that a program did not include a newline to end the ultimate line of output:

```
% PS1="someothershellprompt "
someothershellprompt printf "hello world"
hello world%
someothershellprompt PS1='%# '
%
```

The fix is to ensure that programs emit lines with ultimate newlines so probably in your case to use `"Hello World!\n"` or some other means of including the ultimate newline.

Without the ultimate newline you can get silent data loss in bad code such as

```
% printf "one\ntwo" | while read line; do echo $line; done
one
%
```

so it's probably best to always include that ultimate newline (pretty sure POSIX demands it be there for a file to be a text file).

(Note that there are a lot of flaws in the above `while` loop. If you are actually planning on doing programming in a shell, especially a POSIX shell (which ZSH is not, by default), the flaws really should be corrected;

```
printf "one\ntwo\n" |\
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do printf '%s\n' "$line"; done
```

or, you could switch to a programming language that has less problematic (and doubtless much faster) line handling capabilities.)

Comment: Seems like a solid answer, thanks